# Can I stop Lync 2010 from automatically adding contacts to my frequent contact list

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, lync, lync-2010

Is there a way to stop Lync from adding contacts automatically to my contact list when I talk to a certain person a couple of times? There's a person I need to remove from my contact list from time to time so their availability doesn't distract me. However, whenever I start talking to them, they get notified they're being added to my contact list, thus letting them know I removed them in the first place. I don't think there's a way to stop sending those notifications on my side, only turning them off on theirs. If I'm wrong, then please correct me. Turning off those notifications would be an even better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know from my experience with Lync, the answer is **no**. In fact it would be irrational to do so. The list of frequent contacts exists to keep the information about people you have contacted frequently. Disabling this functionality defeats the purpose of having it.

I completely understand the reason why one would not want to see the list of frequent contacts. If you don't want to see it you can choose to hide it. People you contact will still be automatically added to the list, but it will not distract you any more.

In the **"View More Layout Options"** dropdown menu, unselect **"Show Frequent Contacts"**

[image]

After that you will only see your main contacts that you have added manually.

Good luck